# How to add trailing m to FullCalendar event time format meridiem?

Tags: time, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar 2.6 and have customized the event time format with these options

```
        displayEventEnd: true,
        timeFormat: 'h:mm t',
```

but when FullCalendar renders the event I get something like '1:00 p - 2:00 p' without an 'm' for 'am' or 'pm'. I have not found an option to get the two letter meridiem other than overriding the event render which seems like overkill. Is there a simple way to add the 'm'?

Answer (score 0):

OK, looked through the JavaScript and found a comment with an example: 'h:mm a' works!